# The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the type 'ScaffoldState'

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is showSnackBar giving the above Error. `

```
IconButton(
  icon: const Icon(Icons.content_copy),
  iconSize: 24,
  onPressed: () {
    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: transaction.transCode));
    scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
      content: Tooltip(
        message: Utils.getString(context, 'transaction_detail__copy'),
        child: Text(
          Utils.getString(context, 'transaction_detail__copied_data'),
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline6!
              .copyWith(color: PsColors.mainColor),
        ),
        showDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      ),
    ));
  },
),
```

`

i have tried changing my Globalkey to Global i end up getting more errors. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

this way of calling of trying to show a snackbar is deprecated, instead, you can use the `ScaffoldMessenger` like this:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
      content: Tooltip(
        message: Utils.getString(context, 'transaction_detail__copy'),
        child: Text(
          Utils.getString(context, 'transaction_detail__copied_data'),
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline6!
              .copyWith(color: PsColors.mainColor),
        ),
        showDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      ),
    ));
```

Check this [page](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger#description-of-change)